# What to do when a private key of an organization in Hyperledger fabric gets compromised?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

Hello I have a Hyperledger Network blockchain network running with 5 organization. If one of the private key of the organization gets compromised what are the steps or methods available to revoke the private key. Are there any mechanisms in Fabric where we can generate  new set of key pair for the same organization .

Answer (score 2):

you can generate new set of key pair from your CA for your organization and then you should update the config block. you can take a look at [this](https://medium.com/@kctheservant/add-a-new-organization-on-existing-hyperledger-fabric-network-2c9e303955b2) article to understand the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the new certificate and private key pair from the Certificate authority and pass it to the configuration. In the meantime, you can add previous the certificate in the Certificate revocation list.